# Qt Creator won't launch on Ubuntu (VBox)

Tags: qt, ubuntu, virtualbox, launch

I just installed Qt Creator on Ubuntu in VirtualBox and it won't launch. Does anyone know what could I do to make it work?

Comment: Are you receving any error or warning?

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely due to the OpenGL requirement not being met, they have a section on their FAQ regarding it: [Creator FAQ](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-faq.html).